# On expressions about "false accusation" and "death penalty"

Tags: expressions

I want to say the following content: "If, after a death penalty is carried out, the case is shown to be false, there is no mending."

Which expression is the most appropriate?
(1) If, after a death penalty is carried out, **he or she** is shown to be falsely accused, there is no mending.

(2) If, after capital punishment is carried out, **the case** is shown to be false, there is no mending.

I'm not sure whether the subject should be "the case" or "a person", although there may be some other mistakes in these sentences.

Comment: ?localized perhaps

Comment: You could speak of discovering that *the accused [person]* was in fact innocent (or at least, not *conclusively proven to be guilty*). Or, you could say *the case against that person* was "false". But in fact we don't normally speak of a case being "false" - it's more likely to be *flawed, unreliable, inconclusive*, etc.

Comment: In the first place, a case is neither true nor false. It is the charges against the defendant that would be true or false. Second, it is difficult to determine what you're really asking here. You seem to be offering us a pile of words and asking us to sort them out for you. If you can refine your question to be less woolly, perhaps this question won't be closed.

Comment: Thank you, Robusto. I'm sorry my question is unclear. I myself am not sure how to ask. I want to know what expression is the best when you want to say the content above.

Comment: @ foolnrony : maybe try using the phrase *miscarriage of justice* and see if you can craft a better sentence.

Answer (score 1):

"If, after the accused is executed, it is shown that someone else committed the crime, there exists no remedy for so great an injustice."

This assumes (rightly) that the topic (use of the death penalty) is central to the language leading up to this particular sentence. It is also favors a less, say, British vernacular.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you want to caution against according the death penalty:

> No recompense is possible in the event that the accused is posthumously proven innocent.